# Remove duplicate pdf pages in Preview?

Tags: macos, pdf, preview

Preview has a pretty clean and efficient PDF editor, especially when it comes to adding and removing pages.

What I'm really looking for is a function that can remove duplicate pages.

I've got a pdf with tons of duplicate pages and it would be really great if there was an option to remove all doubles.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Click 'View' in the toolbar > Thumbnails. Then highlight the duplicated page, press delete to remove it.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn’t clear enough, I was looking for a more automated way to find & remove duplicate pages.

Comment: You should probably update your question with that additional info as it's pretty important.